# UnboundLocalError in recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I am coding a neural network using the swish activation function and had the idea of doing the backpropagation using recursion. Here is the code for the portion where I deal with the coefficients beta inside the swish functions:

```
import numpy as np
def beta_gradient(depth,weight_matrices,bias_vectors,beta_vectors,layers):
    weight_matrix = weight_matrices[-1]
    bias_vector = bias_vectors[-1]
    beta_vector = beta_vectors[-1]
    len_current_layer = len(beta_vector)
    if depth == 0:  
        beta_gradient = np.zeros((len_current_layer,len_current_layer))
        for i in range(len_current_layer):
            beta_gradient[i,i] = swish_gradient(beta_vector[i],np.dot(weight_matrix[i,:],layers[-2])+bias_vector[i])[0]
        return beta_gradient
    else: 
        diagonal = np.zeros((len_current_layer,len_current_layer))
        for i in range(len_current_layer):
            diagonal[i,i] = swish_gradient(beta_vector[i],np.dot(weight_matrix[i,:],layers[-2])+bias_vector[i])[1]
        beta_gradient = diagonal.dot(weight_matrix).dot(beta_gradient(depth-1,weight_matrices[:-1],bias_vectors[:-1],beta_vectors[:-1],layers[:-1])) 
        return beta_gradient
    
weights = [np.array([[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]), np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])]
biases = [np.zeros(3), np.zeros(2)]
betas = [np.ones(3),np.ones(2)]
layers = [np.ones(2),np.ones(3),np.ones(2)]
beta_gradient(1,weights,biases,betas,layers)
```

When I run this code I get the following error

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'beta_gradient' referenced before assignment
```

The code is a bit involved. However, my question is simple: if I change the name of the variable beta_gradient (inside the function beta_gradient()) to something else (say I call it "gradient"), then the code runs ok. Would anyone know why this happens? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a variable `beta_gradient` in your function why leave that like this?

Comment: Because, if you enter the `else` branch, where you try to make a recursive call to `beta_gradient`, but it is a local variable. So hence, the error

Comment: scopes in python work in strange ways

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre eh, I don't know if it's that strange. Javascript does the opposite, assignment will default to global, which is a notorious source of bugs. Ruby works the same way as Python, IIRC

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga when you can avoid name collisions (which is _everytime_) just do it. Else, wonder about strange things happening (note that the duplicate is a question I asked :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I will stick to avoiding name collisions, thank you.